# Separate file server for php website + linux

Tags: linux, php-5.3

I have one linux server for my website which contain php code,database and files.

files are being uploaded and downloaded by enduser for their individual tasks. My website is working fine but as website evolove these files volume will be increased so my webserver will be overloaded.

So I want to use seperate server for files so that burden on 1 webserver will be decrease and files will be downloaded and uploaded on another server.

Can anyone suggest me best way to achieve that. I know the files can be transferred to another server by FTP functions of php just after uploading through website but doesn't seems a correct way.

Answer (score 0):

option 1 (simple): you have the upload form post to the second server rather than handling the upload with the server that runs the rest of the application

option 2: (in most cases wrong approach) have the receiving script on server 1 store it in the db, and server 2 when checking for the download pull it from db and cache it locally.

option 4: (my favorite) put a reverse proxy (for example varnish) on server 1, let the application run on server 2, and have the proxy cache static files for , so the reverse proxy will handle the downloads (and other static files like images, javascript etc.) if available. This allows you for a few other tricks to improve your performance as well (like caching sites that can be cached). https://www.varnish-cache.org/